# How do I skip a datapoint in Highcharts without causing an interruption in the line of the chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Using Highcharts ...
I have a series of values that corresponds with a series of times. Sometimes, the data value is `null` on a specific time and no marker is placed on the chart, which is good, but the line gets interrupted and basically starts a new chart on the next value that is not `null`.

I would like to skip the `null` values on the chart, but still keep the time values and just connect the last non-null value to the next with a solid line.

- I have tried skipping the entire index if the value is `null`, but then the time value is skipped as well.
- I have replaced the `null` with `0`, but obviously then the data points lands on the 0-axis.

This is my data:

```
for (i = 0; i < tpoints.length; i++)
    {
        var tc = cpoints[i];
        var tf = fpoints[i];
        var t = tpoints[i];
        labels.push(t);
        c.push(tc);
        f.push(tf);
    }
```

This is my chart config:

```
var config = {
        type: 'line',
        fill : false,
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                    data: f,
                    backgroundColor: [
                        color(window.chartColors.red).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
                    ],
                    label: '',
                    fill : false
                },{
                    data: c,
                    backgroundColor: [
                        color(window.chartColors.blue).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
                    ],
                    label: '',
                    fill : false
                }],
            labels: labels
        },
        options: {
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            responsive: true,
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: title,
                fontSize: 22
            },
            legend: {
                position: "bottom",
                display: false
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'T'
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
            }
        }
    };
```

This creates the line-chart as expected (**Color dots for each data point. Each data dot is then connected with a thin grey line.**), but somewhere in the middle of the chart, if it receives a `null` value, the grey line gets cut and only displays again between two non-null values.

**Any ideas on how i can connect the data point before the `null` with the data point after the `null`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the `connectNulls` option:

```
series: [{
    data: [...],
    connectNulls: true
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fheb9yp5/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.connectNulls

Answer (score 0):

can you show us how your data shows up? if the null values ​​have a meaning in your treatments I suggest you change the type of graph or replace the null values ​​by zero